# Swift compiler warning - Instance method took ###ms to type-check (limit: 100ms)

Tags: swift, xcode, compile-time-type-checking

After adding

```
    if urlString == nil || urlString!.count == 0
    {
        return
    }
```

To this function:

```
func selectItem(urlString: String?)
{
    if urlString == nil || urlString!.count == 0
    {
        return
    }


    if let item: AVPlayerItem = self.getPlayerItem(for: urlString!)
    {
        self.playerQueue.replaceCurrentItem(with: item)
    }
}
```

XCode started to complain on long type-checking:

> Instance method 'selectItem(urlString:)' took 100ms to type-check
> (limit: 100ms)

Comment: You can try removing the first `if` and make the second one like this: `if let urlString = urlString, !urlString.isEmpty, let item: AVPlayerItem = self.getPlayerItem(for: urlString)`

Comment: Yep. But I still do not understand why it takes so much time

Comment: Because the complexity of `String.count` is `O(n)`. You should check `String.isEmpty` instead.